# Report Viewer SP 1 and Chrome/Safari

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I recently installed the Report Viewer SP 1 patch and I still was unable to see the results of a report in safari or chrome.  Exporting the report works fine, but not viewing the results right in the report viewer itself.  So SP 1 didn't help, even though I thought I saw a matrix that said it would.  Is there a way to get Safari and Chrome working with the latest report viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to apply the updated doc type:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

And then it started to work great.